# glPushName + glPopName stack overflow and underflow

Tags: opengl, selection, stack-overflow, picking, stackunderflow

Can anybody explain me how to use glPushName and glPopName. I like to use them instead of glLoadName, but I laways get GL_STACK_OVERFLOW and GL_STACK_UNDERFLOW errors. (First, under then overflow).

Example code would help me too.

Note #1:
My Rendering/selection_rednering code consists of multiple glBegin(...)/glEnd() blocks, if this is any problem plus various Rotations and Transformations.

Note #2:
I know that GL selection / picking is deprecated, but I have to implement it within a Application which was developed a with OpenGL2.1 a while ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I was just dumb, because that stackoverflow was caused by doing to much glPushMatrix, as that stack has a very low capacity (3 in my special hardware case). Drawing mode worked just fine, but I have an additional Matrix used for picking mode.

How to use glPopName /glPushName(name)

```
glPushName(obj->name());
glBegin(...);
//draw it;
glEnd();

glPushName(obj->child->name());
glBegin(...);
//draw child it;
glEnd();

glPopName();
glPopName(); //important, or yoou will get a stackoverflow after some time
```